# VueJs Scrolling to component by url hash data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on implementing a solution to scrolling to certain type of components by the data available from url hash(`window.location.hash`)

There's a parent component `componentA` with multi-level sub components `subComponentA` and `subComponentB` with more components `subSubComponentA` and `subSubComponentB` under it to be scrolled to.

I'm considering the following methods and wondering which is the best to implement in this usecase,

1. Set #`id` directly on each of these components, and find the element by `id` and scroll to it based on offsetTop.
2. Set refs on level-1 sub-components and level-2 sub components, and map the level-2 refs on grand parent level, and scroll to the element based on it.

Or is there a better way to implement such scrolling mechanism.

any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using vue-router? if so, use [scrollBehavior](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)

Comment: @JacobGoh Not using vue-router.

Comment: if scrolling animation is not required, it will work just by setting `window.location.hash`  to the elem ID. Else, why not just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto